# VBA updating links in for loop happening too slowly

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks: MainWorkbook, SourceWorkbook.

Basically, I have the user input a list of stock tickers in MainWorkbook. SourceWorkbook does calculations based off of one stock ticker and then outputs information. I'm displaying some of this information in the MainWorkbook (for every stocker ticker that the user inputs).

**The process for this is (e.g. pseudocode)**

For every ticker:

1. Change ticker in SourceWorkbook

   2. Update links in MainWorkbook (so the
      new information is pulled in)
   3. Paste the information that was pulled in to MainWorkbook as values
      Go to next ticker

**Here is my code:**

```
For Each ticker In tickers_array
    source_book.Worksheets("Calculation").Range("D4") = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Detailed Exhibit").Cells(7, current_ticker_col).Value
    ThisWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources, Type:=xlExcelLinks
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Detailed Exhibit")
        .Range(.Cells(9, current_ticker_col), .Cells(29, current_ticker_col + 4)).Value = .Range(.Cells(9, current_ticker_col), .Cells(29, current_ticker_col + 4)).Value
    End With
    current_ticker_col = current_ticker_col + 4
Next
```

Note: I show the information for each stock ticker in rows 9 - 29 in 4 columns (hence updating the current_ticker_col by 4 with each loop).

The problem I'm having is that the links never update, so I just end up pasting all of the formulas as values, so MainWorkbook only shows the information for whatever stock ticker was in SourceWorkbook initially.

Comment: Is your link/query set to run in the background?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by this. Could you help me understand? I'm using formulas in MainWorkbook to pull in information from the SourceWorkbook (and then pasting these as values before I move onto the next ticker).

Comment: What does `source_book` do with the stock ticker when you paste it in?  Is it running a query, or just performing calculations with worksheet formulas?

Comment: That's an alternative, but I've already done a bunch of work to use this methodology, so I'm hoping someone will have a solution besides that.

Comment: source_book is just performing calculations with worksheet formulas

Comment: I can't really imagine your setup - do you have all of your linked cells pointing at the same block of cells in `source_book`?  If you put a break within your loop after calling updatelink does it "catch up" ?

Comment: That's correct. And I just added in a breakpoint into the loop and it looks like even with that, the formulas don't update.

Comment: Maybe try calling `Calculate` on the range in question?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.calculate  Is calculation set to automatic?